# In Cura, is it possible to display where retraction occur on any given model?

Tags: slicing, retraction

In Cura slicer, it is possible to display\visualize where in the print process retractions occur for any given model?

For example, to have them highlighted in the preview window.

I'm making my own models\sculpts and want to optimise them to reduce the amount of time that retraction occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it ss possible to visualize the retractions in the preview of the sliced object in Cura.

[image]

In the "Preview" window mode with "Layer view" option enabled (after you sliced the object), you are able to select the "Line Type" of the "Color scheme" and enable travel lines. Dark blue lines are unretracted and light blue is retracted.

[image]